# WSO2 EI: WSDL Not opening in the management console

Tags: wso2, wsdl, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

WSDL 1.1 & WSDL 2.0 are not opening in the management console when I open the WSDL in the management console it shows *This site can’t be reached* error I don't know why this happening. So please help me to sort this out.

Note: No error throws in both carbon and wire logs

[image: Management Console]
[image: Management Console]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you have misconfiguration problem i think. becouse you have wso2 in AWS and this ip-10-50-11-169... is not a hostname or your ip adress.
Can you check your /etc/hosts on server? maybe you must change fqdn in aws account

or you can check wso2 hostname/ip adress configuration in axis2.xml <parameter name="WSDLEPRPrefix"..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following property to your `axis2.xml` to pick the correct FQDN/Hostname when generating WSDL URLs. So add the Hostname you are using to access the services here or if you are using the same hostname used for management console add the hostname with the correct service port.(8280 or 8343)

```
<parameter name="WSDLEPRPrefix" locked="false">http://ei.wso2.com:80</parameter>
```

Refer to instructions [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Clustering+the+ESB+Profile#ClusteringtheESBProfile-Configuringclustersettings).

Also, make sure the FQDN is resolvable and your security groups are allowing access to relevant ports.